# Change highest values to lowest values python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a matrix with zeros in the diagonal and highest value is e.g. is 20 and the lowest is 1, I want now to change the 20 to the 1, the 19 to the 2 and also the other way, 1 to 20, 2 to 19. The diagonal should still remain zero or take an infinte value.
Currently I just know how to scale them but not. If this question is a duplicate please direct me, I could not find an answer.

```
matrix=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(4, 4)), 
columns=list('ABCD'))
matrix.values[[np.arange(len(matrix))]*2]=0
#this is just scaling down, which Idont want
revisedmatrix=(1./(matrix+1))
revised.values[[np.arange(len(revised))]*2]=0
```

Comment: you mean something like `21 - matrix` and then reset the diagonal (`np.fill_diagonal(matrix.values, 0)`)?

Comment: yeah something like that but I do not know my maximum all time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract the max value from `matrix`:

```
matrix = matrix.values.max() + 1 - matrix
```

Now, fill the diagonal with zeros:

```
matrix.values[(np.arange(len(matrix)),) * 2] = 0
```

Or, using `np.fill_diagonal` as suggested by @AChampion in the comments:

```
np.fill_diagonal(matrix.values, 0)
```